# Git and continuous integration

Tags: version-control, git, continuous-integration

After using SVN for years I'm finally trying to learn Git.  The tutorial explains how with Git you commit to your local repo for much of the time.  I thought Git was supposed to make continuous integration easier, but if you're committing to a local repo for most of the time, isn't that tantamount to working in isolation and having more conflicts when merging with the central repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't impose any particular way of working on you. Most Git *commands* work on your local repository only, with only the push/pull/fetch commands actually doing things with a remote repository.

In particular, you can still *push* to a remote repository just as often as you would do a remote commit with Subversion.